# Xamarin iOS NetworkReachability.SetNotification not firing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement a simple notifier that will broadcast a message when the network connectivity changes in an app.

The problem I am having is that although the class returns the correct connection status when my code asks for it, the .SetNotification method of my networkreachability object does not get fired when the connection status changes.

Here is my connection status checking code, if anyone could help highlight what I have done wrong it would be much appreciated, thank you.

```cs
public event EventHandler ReachabilityChanged;

public NetworkStatus Status ()
{
    if(_defaultRouteReachability == null)
    {
        _defaultRouteReachability = new NetworkReachability(new IPAddress(0));
    }

    _defaultRouteReachability.SetNotification(OnChange);
    _defaultRouteReachability.Schedule(CFRunLoop.Current, CFRunLoop.ModeDefault);
    _defaultRouteReachability.TryGetFlags (out _flags);

    return ParseFlags ();
}

NetworkStatus ParseFlags ()
{
    if (_flags == 0)
        return NetworkStatus.NotReachable;

    if (_flags.HasFlag(NetworkReachabilityFlags.ConnectionRequired)   ||
        _flags.HasFlag(NetworkReachabilityFlags.InterventionRequired) ||
        _flags.HasFlag(NetworkReachabilityFlags.ConnectionOnDemand))
    {
        return NetworkStatus.NotReachable;  
    }

    if (_flags.HasFlag (NetworkReachabilityFlags.TransientConnection) || 
        _flags.HasFlag (NetworkReachabilityFlags.IsWWAN))
    {
        return NetworkStatus.ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork;
    }

    return NetworkStatus.ReachableViaWiFiNetwork;
}

void OnChange(NetworkReachabilityFlags flags)
{
    var h = ReachabilityChanged;
    if (h != null)
        h(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what's wrong with your approach, but I've done that a few days ago, so here's my working example:

https://thomasbandt.com/how-to-check-network-reachability-with-xamarinios-on-ios-8

Answer (score 0):

You should try using ready [Connectivity Plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/connectivityplugin) available in xamarin, really handy to use.

It is a Simple cross platform plugin to check connection status of mobile device, gather connection type, bandwidths, and more.